# VB storing text from txt file to 2D array using Comma Delimiter

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file, text, 2d

I've searched for an answer, but struggling to adapt my findings into my code/text file.

I have this text file; 
20,Ben
10,Dave
7,Bob

Scores and names.

I want pull the data from the text file into a 2D array, for example:

array(0, 0)
array(1, 0)
array(0, 1)
array(1, 1)
array(0, 2)
array(1, 2)

which would translate to;

array(20)
array(Ben) 
array(10)
array(Dave)
array(7)
array(Bob)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you use a class for this? For example `Player` with two properties: `Name As String` and `Score As Int32`. Then you can create a `List(Of Player)` instead. That's much more readable, reusable and maintainable and also less error-prone than fiddling around with indices.

Comment: Agreed...unless this is for homework and you're required to use a 2D array?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. I should have mentioned I'm very new to VB (few hours or so). My plan was to let the player, play the game, when it's game over ask the player for their name. And store it in the text file with the score. A leaderboard can then be pulled from the text file and displayed on a different form

Comment: nope, no homework. Just something I'm trying on the side.

Comment: Make a class as Tim suggested, then, and use XmlSerializer to read/write the file.

Comment: @Idle_Mind -- don't you think using the XMLSerializer is overkill?  He already stated he's very new, and that would be quite the learning curve for him.  Using .NET's built in text file manipulation functionality in System.IO would make more sense in this case.  Using System.IO.File.ReadAllLines() to pull the data into an array and then instantiate the class you suggested would be much easier for a beginner.

Comment: Perhaps...you can serialize/deserialize XML in like three lines of code though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment,i would use a class for this.

For example `Player` with two properties: `Name As String` and `Score As Int32`. Then you can create a `List(Of Player)` instead. That's much more readable, reusable and maintainable and also less error-prone than fiddling around with indices.

```
Public Class Player
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Score As Int32
End Class
```

Here is a readable LINQ query that initializes a `List(Of Player)` from lines in a text-file:

```
Dim allPlayers = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("path")
                 Let Columns = line.Split(","c)
                 Where Columns.Length = 2
                 Let Score = Int32.Parse(Columns(0).Trim())
                 Let Name = Columns(1).Trim()
                 Select New Player With {.Score = Score, .Name = Name}
Dim playerList As List(Of Player) = allPlayers.ToList()
```

If you need an array use `ToArray` instead of `ToList`.

You can access alist like an array via indexer(`list(0)`) or via LINQ methods:

```
Dim firstPlayer As Player = playerList.FirstOrDefault()  ' is Nothing if there are no players '
Console.WriteLine("Name of the player: " & firstPlayer.Name)
Console.WriteLine("His score is: " & firstPlayer.Score)
```

or in a loop:

```
For Each player In playerList
    Console.WriteLine("Player {0} has scored {} points.", player.Name, player.Score)
Next
```

By the way, LINQ is useful to keep your code readable, under the hood it also uses loops. So you could simply use [`OrderByDescendending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548916%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to order your players by score and output the top 3 with the highest score:

```
Dim best3Players = From player In playerList
                   Order By Player.Score Descending
                   Take 3
                   Select String.Format("{0}({1})", player.Name, player.Score)
Dim output = String.Join(", ", best3Players)
Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(output) ' since you have mentioned messagebox '
```

Comment: Thank again Tim, I have done this and seems to pulling the data into the 'list'. I've just discovered the Autos window in Visual Studio 2010 which has each of the players and there score paired up. How do use these names and scores. For example; to display a name or score in a msgbox. I've tried MsgBox(0, Name, Score),  MsgBox(0.Name, Msgbox(playerList, 0, Name), MsgBox(playerList(0))...

Comment: @BenBowden: Have you noticed that i've already edited my answer?

Comment: Tim, that is absolutely stunning lol. I've used your first, second and last code snippet and it works great... simply display the top three player... It's only taken 6 hours haha. Thanks again, if anything else gets me stuck I know where to come.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the file is not going to be terribly big, the simplest approach would be to simply use the `File.ReadAllLines` method, which returns a single-dimension array of strings containing one item per line in the file.  You could then loop through each line and use the `String.Split` method to split apart the two values from the line, for instance:

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines("leaderboard.csv")
Dim values(lines.Length - 1, 1) As String
For i As Integer = 0 to lines.Length - 1
    Dim parts() As String = lines(i).Split(","c)
    values(i, 0) = parts(0)
    values(i, 1) = parts(1)
Next
```

However, it would be better if you created a class to store all of the data from each row, like this:

```
Public Class LeaderboardEntry
    Public Property PlayerName As String
    Public Property Score As Integer
End Class
```

Then, you could load the values into a list of those objects, like this:

```
Dim entries As New List(Of LeaderboardEntries)()
For Each i As String In File.ReadAllLines("leaderboard.csv")
    Dim parts() As String = lines(i).Split(","c)
    Dim entry As New LeaderboardEntry()
    entry.Score = parts(0)
    entry.PlayerName = parts(1)
    entries.Add(entry)
Next
```

Then, instead of saying `values(0, 0)` to get the score of the first entry, you would say `entries(0).Score`, which is much more readable, especially if you add more fields to each line in the file.  For more information on the value of using a class for something like this, check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14086535/1359668).

Bear in mind however, that the above code assumes that each line is properly formatted.  If the file contained any lines that did not include a comma, it would fail.  If you need to handle that situation, you'd need to add some extra checking.  Also, in the above scenario, the player name cannot contain any commas.  The best way to handle that would be to use proper CSV formatting, like this:

```
30,"Doe, John"
```

And then your quotes would need to be escaped, etc., in which case, it would be worth using the `TextFieldParser` class to read the CSV file rather than reinventing the wheel.  Another option would be to simply disallow the users from entering a comma in their name.  If you take that approach, however, it would be better to pick a less common character for your delimiter, such as a pipe symbol (`|`).

Instead of using a CSV file, I would recommend using an XML file.  Then you could easily store the data, even if it grows in complexity, and read and write to it using either the `XmlSerializer`, `XmlDocument`, or `XDocument`.

If all you need to do is store simple values like this, though, an even better option may to be to use the `My.Settings` feature.

Comment: Thanks Steven for the reply. I didn't get a chance you try your suggestion out as I tried Tim's first and it work. But thanks :)