# How to Link Three Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have three arrays that are displayed next to each other. For a project I have to store patient names, heights and weights. I then have to display the arrays in a sorted list arranged by name. I use a bubble sort for names however when the names are sorted, the patient heights and weights do not sort with the name, so the names do not match with the correct heights and weights of the patients. How can I get the heights and weights to stay with the correct patient name when the list of names are sorted?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Welcome to OOP 101.

```
Public Class Patient

  Public Property Name As String = String.Empty

  Public Property Height As Decimal = 0

  Public Property Weight As Decimal = 0

End Class
```

Then create an array of Patient objects, and sort it.

```
Dim patients As List(Of Patient) = New List(Of Patient)
'  Plug the array in to your bubble sort, or use the built in sort procedures.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I will try this tomorrow. So is this the only other method to solve my problem?

Comment: No.  There are many ways to skin a cat.  You could continue to store all three data about the patients in three separate arrays, and then when you sort the one array, always do the same operation to the other two arrays at the same time to keep them in sync, but that would be silly.  Creating a class to encapsulate all of the data about each patient, as suggested here, is a much better approach.  [My Answer to this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14086535/1359668) explains the difference between these two approaches.

Comment: Public Class Patient

  Public Property Name As String = String.Empty

  Public Property Height As Decimal = 0

  Public Property Weight As Decimal = 0

    End Class

Comment: is that code a form or what is it because it is public class and end class

Comment: It's a *class*, as the code declares. It sounds as though you would benefit from reading a book or four on object-oriented programming and design.

Comment: After creating this array of objects, how can I use three textboxes to fill each part of the array: name, height, weight.

Comment: That's a separate question and will need to be submitted as such. I suggest you do so research on your own first or you will not get a positive response from this site.

Comment: @Marcel, if this answers your question, you should mark it as so (+1, btw Dan-o).

Comment: Thankyou it helped me but I am getting more errors however they are being answered in another question