# Dynamically retrieve Oracle data from double parameter?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I have names and surnames to retrieve from DB, but It's not working as It should. I get names and surnames from a table where they are in separated columns. Names/surnames are displayed in combobox/textbox combination on my form. Now I need to retrieve this data, but there are only 4 fields in my DB to search, because all names/surnames are combined together in those fields (user request). My code works for 2 searches at a time, but not for all 4. Here is my code:

EDIT (this works now - I've separated parameters and added bracket in OR statements):

```
       Using con As New OracleConnection("Data Source=myDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")
              con.Open()

              Using cmd As New OracleCommand()
                 Dim SQL As String = "Select * FROM MyTable "
                 Dim conca As String = " Where "

                 Dim Person1 As String
                 Person1 = CmbName.Text.Trim & " " & TxtSurname.Text.Trim

                    If Not CmbName.Text = "" Then
                        SQL = String.Concat(SQL, conca, " (USER1 = :user OR USER2 = :user1)")                    
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("user", Person1))
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("user1", Person1))
                        conca = " and "
                    End If

                 Dim Person2 As String
                 Person2 = CmbName1.Text.Trim & " " & TxtSurname1.Text.Trim

                     If Not CmbName1.Text = "" Then
                        SQL = String.Concat(SQL, conca, " (ADMINISTRATOR1 = :admin OR ADMINISTRATOR2 = :admin1)")
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("admin", Person2)) 
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("admin1", Person2)) 
                        conca = " and "
                     End If

                 'Retrieve data using execute reader
                 cmd.Connection = con
                 cmd.CommandText = SQL
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                 Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                 Dim dt As New DataTable
                 dt.Load(dr)
                 DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        End Using
```

I tried using brackets between "and" & "or", but this still doesn't work. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't like your approach, you should separate the queries or have one function retrieving results for you for each "Person" request. For your solution try to remove this: `conca = " and "` from the first and second '`if/else`' statement. Add each result into your datatable and then load the gridview with the datatable.

You should call a function similar to this to get the results in a data reader and then feed your datatable. This way you can separate your queries. The tricky part is to have an elegant way to load your datagridview. My suggestion is to stop using datatables (they are very bad). You should use `IEnumerable` or `List (Of Object)` where you could add the results from each query.

```
 Public Shared Function GetMeDatareader(yourQuery As String) As OracleDataReader
        Using con As New OracleConnection("Data Source=myDB;User Id=Lucky;Password=MyPassword;")

            con.Open()

            Using cmd As New OracleCommand()
                Dim SQL As String = yourQuery

                'Retrieve data using execute reader
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = SQL
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Return dr
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

Comment: thanks for response. I think I cannot remove conca=" and " because this is only a snapshot from code, I concatenate a lot more in Query. Take a look at my edited question, this now works for me. If you have better suggestion for me - like to write shorter code, please let me know how.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 If it works then ok. But you should create a dynamic function which retrieves the results for you, then you merge everything into one table and present the data: dtAll = dtOne.Copy() 
dtAll.Merge(dtTwo)

Comment: do you have a link to any example of this ?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 You could add more to this function as input parameters such as your query parameters etc.

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Note that if you use only datareader your application will be much faster. Datatables are very slow and consume a lot of memory. You should create a Person class and create objects for each result and then load them into the datagridview. Remember to close the datareader (i forgot to close it in the code above).

Comment: Create a person class ? This is also something new to me, how to do It? I'm VB.NET beginner, could you show example of that too?

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 Read this and study classes. They are the way to go for proper programming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085784/vb-net-what-is-the-purpose-of-a-class-or-module

Comment: Ok, i'll take a look. I know the basic difference though, just never done a custom class before, that's why I asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122654/discussion-between-luckyluke82-and-alwaysvbnet).