# How to fix previous item of a variable gets sent instead of the current one

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net program that keeps track of people that bought raffle tickets and also keeps track of their phone numbers. When I go to add a new person(via a for loop) it gets the number of tickets they bought and adds that amount of there name and number to an array. But when I click it, it adds one extra of the prevoius name and number I had put in.

I have tried moving the place where the variable assignment takes place.
I tried to null the variable and reassign it.

Button Click

```
    Public Sub BtnAddtckt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    BtnAddtckt.Click
    Reset()
    Dim MNES As String = Nameinput.Text.ToString
    Dim NUMES As String = Numinput.Text.ToString
    Dim LenPrev = ApplicantsName.Length - 1
    Dim LenNext = (LenPrev) + (NumEntries.Value - 1)
    ReDim Preserve ApplicantsName(LenNext)
    ReDim Preserve ApplicantsNum(LenNext)

    For Subs As Integer = LenPrev To LenNext




        ApplicantsNum(Subs) = NUMES
        ApplicantsName(Subs) = MNES

    Next
    LbltotalRegistered.Text = (ApplicantsName.Length - 1).ToString


    For nme As Integer = 0 To (ApplicantsName.Length - 1)

        Form2.LBname.Items.Add(ApplicantsName(nme).ToString)
    Next
    For nem As Integer = 0 To (ApplicantsNum.Length - 1)
        Form2.LBnum.Items.Add(ApplicantsNum(nem).ToString)
    Next

End Sub
```

I expect it to not add an extra person to each aray.

Comment: You're adding a new item to the arrays every time the button is clicked.  You need to change it so that it only adds  the new item if it's not already there.  If it's already in the list, it should just update the existing item instead of adding a new one.  Also, some advice: I am hard pressed to think of any good reason for using `ReDim Preserve`.  Use a `List(Of String)` instead.  Oh, and while we're at it, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14086535/1359668).

Comment: Could you show me how to fix this in my code? I'm not familiar with how to use the List(Of String)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out!